# How to check if what a user has written is blank when asking for an input?

Tags: python

I am creating a little game for a project that I am working on for college. I am wondering how it would be possible to check if what the user has inputted for the variable 'playerName' is **blank** seeing as I don't want player names to just be nothing. I gathered you could just do an if statement such as [if playerName == "":] however is there a way to cover problems where the user for instance just spams their keyboard with spaces?

```
playerList = []
  for participant in range(1,participants+1):
    playerName = input("Enter the name of participant number "+str(participant)+": ")
    playerList.append(playerName)
```

Comment: `if playerName == '':`?

Comment: An empty string is false.  `if not playerName:`

Answer (score 1):

`.strip()` will remove leading and trailing whitespace.  `if not playerName:` will check that the result is not completely empty.  Put in a while loop and break when it is non-empty.

```
playerList = []
participants = 2
for n in range(participants):
    while True:
        playerName = input(f'Enter the name of participant number {n + 1}: ').strip()
        if not playerName:
            print('name cannot be blank')
        else:      
           break
    playerList.append(playerName)
print(playerList)
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension would be an option here, coupled with a function to read in a single player's name.

```
def getPlayerName(n):
  while True:
    playerName = input(f'Enter the name of participant number {n}: ').strip()
    if not playerName:
      print('name cannot be blank')
    else:      
      return playerName

playerNames = [getPlayerName(n+1) for n in range(participants)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code checks if the string is empty or contains whitespaces

```
if not playername and len(playername.strip()) > 0:
    playerList.append(playerName)
```